# Obtain Message-ID: header of sent mail in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, smtp, mime-headers

Assuming a vanilla POP3 account in Outlook, how does one get
the `Message-ID:` header of sent email?

Alternatively, the raw MIME object as submitted to the SMTP
server would be equally valuable. E. g. a way of making
Outlook dump every message it sends into a text file.

This concerns Outlook 2013+. The problem is some ERP system
sending email via MAPI which appears to generate defective MIME
structures. Customer claims “it did work before!”

(There are numerous how-tos online that point to the menu
„File → Properties → Internet Headers“ but the version of
Outlook I have access to, it shows no headers there at all.)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there should be message internet headers no matter which version you have(Outlook 2010-365). Please make sure you open the message in a new window first, then click File > Properties, here you can see the internet headers.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that it’s not enough to select the message; when I open the message I now get that “Properties” menu. However, the “Internet Headers” field is empty and grayed out. No Message-Id: there.